# What are all the inventory items?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

I have been playing the Majora's Mask remake for the 3DS. I have collected all the heart pieces, masks, and everything I can remember from the N64 version but there is still an empty spot in my inventory. I'd like a list so that I can cross reference, I've checked a few from the N64 version but due to the reworked system not all the items on those lists apply. What are all the inventory items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just type all of them

- Arrow and the three type of arrows
- Bomb
- Bombchu
- Deku stick
- Deck nut
- Magic beans
- Powder keg
- Pictograph box
- Lens of truth
- Hook shot
- Great fairy sword
- 7 bottles

That is all of them

If that doesn't help here is a [walk through](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/majoras-mask-walkthrough/) just read it and find what you are missing